# Printing Jasper report data in matrix format

Tags: pdf, matrix, jasper-reports, tabular

I have a situation where I need to print data in matrix format.
I have main report and subreport. From the main report I am passing a list (objects) to the subreport. Inside the subreport I have to print object data in tabular/matrix format as below:

```
___________________________________
| Name1    |  Name2     | Name3    |
| Address1 |  Address2  | Address3 |
| Phone1   |  Phone2    | Phone3   |
|__________|____________|__________|
| Name1    |  Name2     | Name3    |
| Address1 |  Address2  | Address3 |
| Phone1   |  Phone2    | Phone3   |
```

Each row will have 3 columns and there will be X no. of rows depending on list length (1 row for list size 3 and 2 for list size 6 etc...)

I am trying to use `crosstab`, but it does not seems to be ideal solution. Please advice me how to achieve this matrix format of report data.

Comment: im not exactly getting the idea, can you put what you want in an image? I will try to answer though

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure i got you, but here:

In the crosstab properties

- in `Row group` add a new group, with `Bucket Expression`
  ($F{REPORT_COUNT}/3)+1
- in `Column group` add a new group, with `Bucket Expression`
  ($F{REPORT_COUNT}%3)+1

In this was, a new row will be started every 3 records, and every row will contain only 3 columns.

Comment: I got it working through Lists for now.. but I will try this out. Thank you.